# Simple Combinations Word problem.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A boy is preparing for test. The teacher gives $30$ questions to study from and will select $10$ out of the $30$. The student only know hows to solve $25$ of the $30$ questions.

What is the probability that the student will get perfect on the test?

I got $11\%$ as my answer from $\binom{25}{10}/\binom{30}{10}$. Am I correct? Thanks

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22285/probability-that-a-random-sample-will-have-certain-elements check this link

Answer (score 0):

Which are the possible exams the teacher can create? Ways to take $10$ from the possible $30$ questions: $\binom{30}{10}$

Which are the possible exams the student will ace? Ways to take $10$ from the known $25$ questions: $\binom{25}{10}$

Which is the probability to ace the exam? $\frac{favorable\ cases}{possible\ cases}=\binom{25}{10}/\binom{30}{10}\approx 11\%$

You were right.